# Start program in response to system events (like ip address changes, etc.)?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, script

I want to start a program in response to system events, such as:

- IP address changes
- WIFI connectivity changes (whether I'm connected, and/or which network I'm connected to)
- Volume (as in disk) changes
- User logs on or off
- System shuts down or restarts

Is there anything built in to do this, or is there a 3rd party tool that can do this for me?

Answer (score 1):

[ControlPlane](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/39644/controlplane) has many of the functions you're looking for, though I don't think it has any rules for connected users.  I've been using it for a few months on my work MBP to switch between home and office and it's been quite good.

Comment: any programmatically way to do this?